# Get most unique combinations of 2 pictures

Tags: mysql

I have a mySQL table that holds n number of pictures.

```
+------------+--------------+
| picture_id | picture_name |
+------------+--------------+
| 1          | ben.jpg      |
| 2          | nick.jpg     |
| 3          | mark.jpg     |
| 4          | james.jpg    |
| ..         | ...          |
| n          | abraham.jpg  |
+------------+--------------+
```

For a web application, i need to display 2 pictures simultaneously where the user can vote for one picture or the other. After voting, the user gets a new set of two pictures.

(application use interface)

```
+---------------------+--------------------+
| Vorte for picture 1 | Vote for picture 2 |
+---------------------+--------------------+
```

I would like to avoid displaying the same combinations as much as possible. I can create a helper table that will hold all possible combinations.

```
+----------------+--------------+--------------+
| combination_id | picture_id_1 | Picture_id_2 |
+----------------+--------------+--------------+
| 1              |            1 |            2 |
| 2              |            1 |            3 |
| 3              |            1 |            4 |
| 4              |            1 |            5 |
| ..             |           .. |           .. |
| (n^2-n)/2      |           .. |           .. |
+----------------+--------------+--------------+
```

but for 100 pictures, that would be (100^2 - 100)/2 = 4950 (edit) rows, and with every added picture the table would grow exponentially. (which is not a big issue in todays computing i suppose)

But how do i query this table in a way that the user always sees as little duplicates as possible.

Expected result:

```
run 1: picture_id's = 4,5 (any numbers between 1 and n)
run 2: picture_id's = 2,7
run 3: picture_id's = 5 and 20
...
```

Comment: How did you get 450 from that?  What do you mean by "with every added picture"?  Are you planning to also do sets of 3, sets of 4, etc?  How would your table handle that arbitrary change?

Comment: Where do you store the user results?  Just self join on the two's IDs where ID of 1 is less than ID of 2 so you get A<B but B<A would never show. and then exclude the ones already for that users results.

Comment: @David Think about a multiplication table. number from 1 to 10, multiplied by each number from 1 to 10. There are 10^2 possible results, half are duplicates. 10 are multiplications of itself. 

With every added picture, i mean the total number of pictures in the database. I am always plannng to display max 2 pictures

Comment: @AntonShumin: Yes, I understand how math works.  But the question implies that you're struggling with it a bit.  For one thing, the equation you show has a *very* incorrect result.  By an order of magnitude.  And the description of the ongoing problem is unclear.  Please clarify the actual problem.

Comment: @AntonShumin: If you're only planning to ever display 2 pictures, then what's the problem?  Where is the "exponential growth" you mentioned?  So far you're only talking about thousands or maybe tens of thousands of records.  Databases are perfectly capable of that volume of data.

Comment: 100 combinations 2 at a time is 4950 not 450  you dropped a 9 in your question.

Comment: @David Ok, sorry, i'll try. I am trying to find a way to setup my database and a query in such a way, that i waste as little resources as i can, but still can display the most number of unique sets to a user. (i see the error now, its 4950 rows)

Comment: SO is a great site to ask questions and get answers: Just be sure to provide a complete [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Before you ask a question consider [talking to the duck first](https://blog.codinghorror.com/rubber-duck-problem-solving/). Yes, I'm serious! To help us help you, generate sample data and expected results. [ascii table](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/) makes the output easy to read! You could also mock up data and the SQL tried using http://rextester.com/ or a similar site.  Pretty much anything is possible; it's a matter of should we do it; not can we.

Comment: @xQbert Thanks man, i've edited the original question with a little more styling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DEMO:http://rextester.com/VNWIOA4679 (added 100 pic samples)  2 sec query for 1 user w/o any indexes.

I see no need for a helper table as the data can easily be constructed on the fly with proper indexes. at 1000 pictures you're looking at 499,500 combinations a user could vote upon.  still easily managed within a database construct as we operate on a set level, not a record level.

Here's one way assuming my own table structures.  I can't think of a more efficient way to store/process the data.

Using this approach as new pictures are added the query will generate a larger and larger combination set but always exclude those on which a user has already voted.  no code changes for new pics, no regenerating sets just processing each time the ones a user hasn't made a selection upon.

```
Create table SO46205797_Pics(
    PICID int);

Insert into SO46205797_Pics values (1);
Insert into SO46205797_Pics values (2);
Insert into SO46205797_Pics values (3);
Insert into SO46205797_Pics values (4);
Insert into SO46205797_Pics values (5);
Insert into SO46205797_Pics values (6);
Insert into SO46205797_Pics values (7);


Create table SO46205797_UserPicResults (
USERID int,
PICID int,
PICID2 int,
PICChoiceID int);

Insert into SO46205797_UserPicResults values (1,1,2,1);
Insert into SO46205797_UserPicResults values (1,1,3,1);
Insert into SO46205797_UserPicResults values (1,1,4,4);
```

> magic happens here the above was just data setup.

```
SELECT A.PICID, B.PICID, C.PICChoiceID
FROM SO46205797_Pics A
INNER JOIN SO46205797_Pics B
 on A.PICID < B.PICID
LEFT JOIN SO46205797_UserPicResults C
  on A.PICID = C.PicID
 and B.PICID = C.PICID2
 and C.USERID = 1
WHERE C.userID is null;
```

Note that if we eliminate the C.userID is null part then we see all of the possible combinations (for user1) (note I treat ID 1, 2 the same as ID 2,1 which I think youw ant) for the 2 photos and which ones the user has selected.  Since we don't want to display that choice again, we use the c.userID is null to exclude combinations the user already made a choice for.

Also when saving data to the userPicResults, you need to ensure PICID1 is always less than PICID2.

A different way to do this is using a not exists which may be slightly faster.

obviously indexes on USERID, PICID, PICID2 and in that order would be beneficial (i'd probably make it the a combined PK) for SO46205797_UserPicResults  and an index on PICID for SO46205797_Pics as the PK.

```
SELECT A.PICID, B.PICID
FROM SO46205797_Pics A
INNER JOIN SO46205797_Pics B
 on A.PICID < B.PICID
WHERE not exists (SELECT * 
                  FROM SO46205797_UserPicResults C
                  WHERE A.PICID = C.PicID
                    and B.PICID = C.PICID2
                    and C.USERID = 1);
```

I considered maintaining a parent/child relationship for each image for each user; but this approach doesn't store the choices for all combinations.

Comment: We could order by rand() and limit 1 in either of these to get a random 2 pictures which a user hasn't made a choice for yet. or we could just order by the index and allow them to process in pic sequence.

Answer (score 0):

The goal of this application is to let people vote for one picture against another, right? Then you need to have some kind of vote results table:

```
vote_results:
| vote_id | user_id | vote_up_picture_id | vote_down_picture_id | ...
```

Then, based on data from this table you can easily show to a user picture pairs, which he haven't seen yet:

```
select first.picture_id, second.picture_id
from pictures as first, pictures as second
where not exists(
    select * from vote_results v 
    where (v.vote_up_picture_id = first.picture_id and v.vote_down_picture_id = second.picture_id)
    or (v.vote_up_picture_id = second.picture_id and v.vote_down_picture_id = first.picture_id)
) and first.picture_id != second.picture_id
order by rand()
limit 1
```

*PS. As you see, there is no need in helper table with combination_id*